# VMware tools warning: Couldn't restart RpcOut channel

Tags: vmware-esxi, rpc, vmware-tools

I have a recently converted a 2008R2 RDS server to a VM.  I'm getting the following error in the Application event logs:

[ warning] [vmusr:vmusr] Couldn't restart RpcOut channel; bad things may happen until the RPC channel is reset.

The warning is generated whenever a user logs into the RDS (but not every time).

My searching hasn't returned any results for this warning other than the C++ source code that generates the warning.

Has anyone come across this warning before and resolved it?

Configuration:

- Windows 2008 R2
- ESXi 6.0
- VM Machine level 8
- VMware Tools version 9.10, build-2476743

Thanks.

Comment: `bad things may happen until the RPC channel is reset` - is that really the text of the message?

Comment: It really is.  Search: https://github.com/drothlis/open-vm-tools/blob/master/lib/rpcChannel/bdoorChannel.c   for the text